# SSH - Interception

Tags: linux, ssh

Really hoping someone here can point me in the right direction,

Expected result: SSH successfully into a remote device.

Challenge/Back story: We have devices out in remote places around the country, These devices do not have a fixed public IP address (Using GSM as its internet breakout) These devices are able to SSH and break out.

My thought, with regards to maintaining these devices is to (if possible) use a server in the cloud as a middle man, have these devices create some sort of a reverse tunnel to our middleman server then have us as admins intercept it or something to that effect.

Again to summarize, 
Device cannot be ssh'd into directly, but can breakout. Aim to be able to hit their terminal from the office.
have been looking at mitmssh but not coming right on that front.
Server A (no fixed address, cannot SSH into it directly but has breakout)

Server B (standard server which can be used as a middle man

Server C (Us admins)

Tried something along the lines of "ssh user@serverA -R serverB:12345:ServerA:22"

Which creates the tunnel, but struggling with grabbing hold of that SSH connection.

Comment: I would connect them to a central point creating a point to point vpn infrastructure via IPsec.

Answer (score 1):

On server A, you should run automatically (e.g. as systemd service, or whatever you can use there) something like

```
ssh userB@serverB -R serverC:1234:serverA:22
```

as userA, where the public key of userA on server A is in the `authorized_keys` file of userB on server B.

To try this out, I'd use a server A where it is easy to get local access by other means, and run the command directly before installing it as a service.

Then on server C, you can do

```
ssh userX@serverB -p 1234
```

where userX is some user on server A.

If something doesn't work, use (multiple) `-v` verbose flags with `ssh` to debug. You can also put the ssh demon(s) on server B and server A in verbose mode, if necessary.

You can also initially leave out `serverC` on the break-out connection, allowing (temporarily) anyone to access, if this verification doesn't work because addresses get NATed etc.

Comment: Thankfully, I have the devices ( some of them) with me so can do this testing without hassle, 

Thanks a mil for your response, will try this right now