# Intercept a SSH connection through a proxy machine and forward it to another (remote) machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshd, macos

I want to design a proxy, whose IP address is public. Clients know the IP address of that proxy and can SSH to it. However, there is a host whose IP address is unknown to the client. The purpose of the proxy is to "intercept" the SSH from the client and *redirect* it to that private host. The following figure demonstrates the problem:

[image]

Server B is the proxy I want to design. The IP address of server A is unknown to Client C. Client C can SSH server B (proxy). Then the proxy (server B) should forward the SSH connection to server A. Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484593/ssh-interception) answer, I tried the following:

1. Inside server A, I run the following command:

   `ssh userB@serverB -R clientC:1234:serverA:22`
2. From client C, I run the following command:

   `ssh userA@serverB -p 1234`

But client C could not establish a connection with server A, and I get the following message:

`ssh: connect to host server B (192.168.2.122) port 1234: Operation timed out`

Can you please tell me how to make the proxy (server B) works?

---

**Solved:**

My approach is correct, all I need to reconfigure the `sshd_config` in both Server A and Server B (proxy):

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
```

Details can be found [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example).

Comment: So you want to execute a man-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: @DopeGhoti not really. I want to access server A without knowing it's IP. The proxy (server B) knows server A's IP. The client can SSH to the proxy, and the proxy will redirect the session to the appropriate host (in the above case, which is server A).

Comment: Can you communicate from C to B on ports other than 1234? Do you know of some reason why communication from C to B would be restricted to certain ports?

Comment: @Kenster, yes I can communicate from C to B using SSH through port 22.

Comment: Solved the problem, my approach is correct, all I need to do is reconfigure the sshd_config to alow TCP forwarding and GatewayPorts to yes. The details are here: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example

Comment: Welcome to the site, and congratulations on figuring out the problem yourself. In order to make the post as useful as possible for a wide range of readers, please remove the solution part from your question and post it as your own answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is correct, all I need to reconfigure the `sshd_config` in both Server A and Server B (proxy):

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding yes
```

Details can be found here [SSH Port Forwarding](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example).

Answer (score 2):

Can you ssh from `clientC` to `serverB`, and from `serverB` to `serverA`?  If so, there's a much simpler solution.  On `clientC`, run:

```
ssh -J userB@serverB userA@serverA
```

This will first ssh to `userB@serverB`, automatically set up port forwarding to ssh on `serverA`, and connect to `userA@serverA` over that forwarded port.

If that's not feasible, you can use your approach with some modifications, assuming no firewalls or other network restrictions that get in the way.

You need to adjust the reverse forwarding command run from `serverA`:

```
ssh userB@serverB -R "*:1234:localhost:22"
```

The `*` here sets the `bind_address`, which is the address that the reverse forward listens on.  From the ssh man page:

> By default, TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to the
> loopback interface only.  This may be overridden by specifying a
> bind_address.  An empty bind_address, or the address ‘*’, indicates
> that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces. Specifying a
> remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's GatewayPorts
> option is enabled (see sshd_config(5)).

So setting `bind_address` lets you listen for connections on all interfaces.  (In your version, you set it to `clientC`, which won't work because `clientC`'s IP address does not refer to a network interface on `serverB`.

You will also need to set `GatewayPorts clientspecified` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  This gives `ssh -R` the permission to bind to a non-loopback interface.

Then you should be able to ssh from `clientC`:

```
ssh userA@serverB -p 1234
```

This type of port forwarding between `B` and `A` is fine for something quick and dirty.  If you want something more production-ready, then consider using something like HAProxy, nginx, or iptables/nftables to handle TCP forwarding instead of forwarding with SSH.

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks for your help though.

Comment: By the way, the Jump -J will not work, because I do not know the IP address of A (perhaps because of its dynamic nature).